# Precedence of operators in python/numpy: epxlicit vs. prefix notation

Tags: python, numpy, operator-precedence

Many Python packages allow explicit and suffix notations for functions, such as `np.max(X)` vs. `X.max()`. In what order does python carry out operations when a mixture of notations is used?

E.g., `np.abs(X).min()` corresponds to `np.max(np.abs(X))` rather than to `np.abs(np.max(X))` - does this reflects a general rule of precedence of the explicit function `np.f(X)` over the suffix notation `X.f()` or does the precedence need to be checked on a case by case basis?

Comment: The two are different. The former is a general function in numpy, and the latter is a method of ndarray.

Comment: @MechanicPig This is a useful clarification. What does it means in terms of the precedence?

Comment: `X` is the argument to the `np.abs` function.  `min/max` is a method of the result of that function call (which will be a `np.ndarray` object).  `numpy` is somewhat unusual in that it provides both function and method versions of many (but not all) operations.  `np.max(x)` does the same thing as `x.max()` (more or less).  There isn't a `X.abs()`.  This isn't a syntax issue.  While there are patterns, you really need to keep the docs at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always left to right, so `np.abs(X).min()` is equivalent to `(np.abs(X)).min()`.

For right to left you would have needed:

```
np.abs(X.min())
```

Comment: What happens when we have two arrays of same shape `a` and `b` and write `a*b.sum()`? Are all expression in multiplcation evaluated before the multiplication?

Comment: @ado `b.sum()` is evaluated before the multiplication. You'll multiply all values of `a` by a scalar

Comment: Thanks! I am dummy. Operands are evaluated before the operation...